# Prove that $S^2 \vee S^2$ is path connected?

Tags: general-topology, path-connected

Prove that $S^2 \vee S^2$ is path connected?

Let $a$ and $b$ be two points in a topological space $X$. A path in $X$ from $a$ to $b$ is a continuous map $f$ from [0,1] to $X$ s.t $f$(0) = $a$ and $f$(1)=$b$.

A topological space X is said to be path connected iff given any two points $a$ and $b$ , there exists a path in $X$ from a to b

I can draw but i can’t give a function.

Comment: What is $s^2$? What is $*$? Did you mean the $2$-dimensional sphere $S^2$ and [the wedge sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedge_sum)? I don't think its the Cartesian product cause otherwise how can you draw it? That would require some serious skill. :)

Comment: @freakisb i mean Spherical coordinates

Comment: I don't even know how that answers my questions...

Comment: @freakish yes $S^2$ and the wedge

Comment: Right, so $S^2$ is path connected (which is a consequence of $S^2\backslash\{p\}$ being homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ - see stereographic projection). The wedge sum of two path connected spaces is also path connected because each point can be connected to the common glueing point.

Comment: @freakish what the function of this?

Comment: $X * Y$ is not usual notation for the wedge of pointed spaces $X$ and $Y$: the wedge is usually written $X \vee Y$. $X * Y$ is the usual notation for the topological join of $X$ and $Y$. As you now write $X \mathop{x} Y$, you almost certainly mean the product $X \times Y$ (as Asaf suggests) and you **definitely** need to start using MathJax to typeset your questions.

Comment: The symbol you're looking for is `\times`, I think.

Comment: You don't need to write down a function in symbols. Instead you can describe it using the fact that $S^2$ is already itself path-connected.

Answer (score 3):

Let $p$ be the joining point, which belongs to both copies of $S^2$.

Let $x_1,x_2\in S^2\vee S^2$. There exist paths $f_1, f_2$ such that $f_i(0)=x_i$ and $f_i(1)=p$. Then consider the path

$$F(t) = \begin{cases} f_1(2t) \ , \ t\in[0,.5) \\  f_2(2-2t) \ , \ t\in[0.5,1]\end{cases}$$

Note, $F(t)$ is sometimes called the path composition of $f_1, f_2^{-1}$ and might be notated $f_1*f_2^{-1}$ (the "inverse" because here I traverse $f_2$ backwards).

There was also nothing special about $S^2$ here.